# Which is the Matlab equivalent to IDL's function bytscl?

Tags: matlab

From IDL code I got

```
openr,1,"measures.dat"

nx=200
ny=100

data=fltarr(200,100)

readf,1,data

iimage,bytscl(data)
iimage,sobel(data)
```

but I can't afford IDL, even isn't near easy to buy a student licence in my contry. Anyway

In a Matlab transcript I wrote:

```
I=importdata('measures.dat');
nx=200; ny=100;
S=reshape(I,nx,ny);

figure(1)
image(S)

B = edge(S,'Sobel',0,'both') ;

figure(2)
image(B)
```

So how bytscl can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Why do you need to scale it?

Comment: Have you read the IDL help for bytscl? The used formula is mentioned in the first paragraph.

Comment: hi there, sorry for this late reply. Well i need to rescale the data because it came from a gravity anomaly, so is not easly observable

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer, thanks for the comments, this version may be wrong but anyway the image data looks better.

```
function [ Y ] = bytscl( X )

m = min( X( : ) ); 
M = max( X( : ) ); 
Top = 255; 

    if isfloat( X ) 
    Fc = ( Top + 0.9999 )*( X - m )/( M - m );
    Y = cast( Fc, 'int8' );
    else
    Ic = ( Top + 1 )*( X - m - 1 )/( M - m ); 
    Y = cast( Ic, 'int8' ); 
    end 

end
```